# React Native "main" Component Not Registered (Invariant Violation)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, javascript-objects, metro-bundler

I'm encountering an issue with my React Native project where I'm getting the following error:

3492ms ERROR Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

I've reviewed my code and the suggestions in the error message, but I'm still unable to resolve the issue. I've made sure that AppRegistry.registerComponent is correctly called with the appropriate component name. I'm using Expo for my project. Here's a simplified version of my relevant files:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "cbdcexpress",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.10.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.24.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  // ... rest of the package.json
}
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "CBDCExpress",
    "slug": "cbdc-express",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "sdkVersion": "49.0.0",
    "platforms": [ "android", "ios" ],
    "description": "Central Bank Digital Currency Express App",
    "androidStatusBar": {
      "backgroundColor": "#2196F3",
      "barStyle": "light-content"
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    }
  }
}
```

app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';

export default function App() {
  return <AppNavigator />;
}
```

I've followed the advice in the error message, cleared the Metro cache, and restarted the Metro server, but the issue persists. I suspect there might be a conflict in my dependencies or a misconfiguration in my project.